# Divide the dataframe to 3 buckets based on sum of one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
c1     c2
user1  5 
user2  3
user3  3
user4  1
```

I want to divide the dataframes into 3 equal groups based on total sum of c2

total sum of c2 = 12/3 = 4

> In this case user1 have value 5 (>4) Ist group , user2 and user3 (total 6) >4(2nd group), and remaining all should be in 3rd group

so my expected dataframe

```
    c1     c2  rank
    user1  5   1
    user2  3   2
    user3  3   2
    user4  1   3
```

I am trying with Window function and custom window function, but no luck so far.

Comment: What code have you tried, and what is the output? I'm a little confused by what you want, also. It seems you want everything grouped by the value in C2?

Comment: @ethan I have given the expected output, can you please check, I am trying to create a custom window function, that's should return the rank values that I have mentioned in the expected output.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Without the existing code, it's hard to see what steps you're missing.